# How to show only the pages that have some data in BIP?

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I've created a .rtf file that has one table. My conditions, for showing the data are:
create section for each table and
don't show the pages if there aren't any data in the table.

So far I've done this:

```
<?if:COL1!='' or COL2!='' or COL3!='' or COL5!='' or COL6!='' or COL7!=''?>
<?for-each@section:G_1?>
TABLE
<?end for-each?>
<?end if?>
```

The result is that I have blank pages and pages that have data one after another, depending of the data.
How can I eliminate those blank pages? Help pls!